# Synchronize amcl_pose with image?

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, So I am trying to collect synchronized pairs of /amcl_pose and /image_rect_color on the Fetch robot. Here's the code I'm running.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# amcl_listener
from copy import deepcopy
import rospy

from math import sin, cos


from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseWithCovarianceStamped as Pose
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
import pdb as pdb

    
class amcl_listener(object):
    def __init__(self):
            # Create a node
        rospy.init_node("amcl_listener")
        self.amcl_list = []
        self.image_list = []
        # Make sure sim time is working
        while not rospy.Time.now():
            pass
        self.img_sub = rospy.Subscriber(
            '/head_camera/rgb/image_rect_color', Image, self.cb_image)
        self.amcl_sub = rospy.Subscriber(
            '/amcl_pose', Pose, self.cb_amcl)
        self.curimg = None
        self.amcl_pose = None
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            pass
        

    def cb_image(self, msg):
        self.curimg = msg
        print "got image at ", rospy.Time.now()
    def cb_amcl(self, msg):
        self.amcl_pose = msg
        print "got amcl at ", rospy.Time.now()
        
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        start = amcl_listener()
```

Here comes the problem, The difference between the time the first image message arrives and the first amcl pose message arrives is close to 2 seconds according to rospy.Time.now(). I tried to compare header stamps but they are also problematic. Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280513/synchronize-amcl_pose-with-image?/) by [aseembits93](https://answers.ros.org/users/33387/aseembits93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [time synchronizer](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Example_.28Python.29) message filter, this is designed to solve this problem for you.

It can subscribe to several different topics and executes its callback with sets of messages which are as close together in time as possible. This will probably mean that some of the first image messages will be discarded until the amcl messages start arriving.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aseembits93](https://answers.ros.org/users/33387/aseembits93/) on 2018-01-23**:
Hi @PeteBlackerThe3rd! I have tried this thing. It doesn't work in my case. I think it works for messages with a similar update frequency. like stereo images. Actually, amcl_pose arrives first! that is the surprising part.